# Weird character being received on API

Tags: php, api, cakephp

I've started to receive weird characters in one of the text field coming from mobile api.

`CWF6+MH Al 'Azeeziyyah`

`FRMP+V8 Zayed`

`JJXG+64 Zayed`

`MJ7G+3H Zayed`

This text field can accept both `Arabic` and `English` characters, `Arabic` is fine so far.

I tried to google for this issue but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestion or advice.

Thanks

Comment: Double check is request form mobile app.

Comment: You may want to provide some more detail about your mobile API.
Is this a POST/GET request?
Did you set the content-type header for the API class / methods being requested?
Several things could be happening here.

But in summary, it's mostly linked to content type and character encoding.
There's also the possibility of the file encoding type being changed when editing code using different code editors.